# Assert type from Member of enum and interface (Typescript 2.9.2)

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have this enum/interface construction :

```
export enum Keys {
 Testing = Testing
}

interface Apis {
    [Keys.Testing]: TestingApi
}

interface TestingApi {
  iAmATest$: Observable<boolean>
}
```

and this functions:

```
 public getApi<T extends keyof Apis>(key: T): 
 Observable<Apis[T] | null> {
    return this.apis.get(key) as Observable<Apis[T]>;
  }

  public getMemberOfApi<T extends keyof Apis, M extends keyof Apis[T]>
  (key: T, member: M): Apis[T][M] {
    return this.getApi(key)
      .pipe(
        filter<T>(t => !!t),
      switchMap((instance: Apis[T]) => {
        return instance[member] as Apis[T][M];
      }),
      first());
  }
```

The `getApi` function works as expected when called with something like `getApi(Keys.Testing)` but I have a problem with the other one.

First Typescript says the type `Api[T][M]` and `Observable[T][M]` are not compatible.

Second, when I ignore the problem and use the function, I get the correct value but Typescript does not recognize the type (in this case `boolean`)

```
getApi(Key.Testing, 'iAmATest$').subscribe(item => item);
```

item does not get any type.

Edit:

I have made a stackblitz with the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-ejg69f?file=index.ts

Edit: So Typescript now gets the type but the compiling says my function is not returning what I am returning.

Comment: pipe() returns an Observable, even when you use first(). Your return type is `Observable<Apis[T][M]>`

Comment: Hi @dezfowler I mean the type inside the subscription I get from the function.

Comment: If I do this in a typescript playground... `const x = t.getMemberOfApi(Keys.Testing, 'iAmATest$');` I get a type of `x` as `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: @dezfowler weird, in my side typescript says it is a observable. Take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-ejg69f?file=index.ts